# How to send data from one application to another application using broadcast android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-broadcast

In Application 1, I am passing action and datas ( i.putExtra("data", "Some data");) and I need to receive this data in Application 2 but it's not receiving this data in 2nd Application. Everything works only within the application 1 but not in application 2. I have registered the specific action of Application 1 in Application 2 (ACTION1 = "com.test.add.mystaticevent";) but broadcast receiver of data in Application 2 is not working.

Application 1:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyBroadcastReceiver MyReceiver;
    public static final String ACTION1 = "com.test.add.mystaticevent";
    public static final String ACTION2 = "com.test.add.mydyanicevent";
    private Button button,button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        button =findViewById(R.id.button);
        button1 =findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.ACTION1);
                i.putExtra("data", "Some data"); //I am passing this data to receive in App2
                i.setPackage("com.test.add"); //in API 26, it must be explicit now.
                //since it's registered as a global (in the manifest), use sendBroadCast
                //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).sendBroadcast(i);
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }
        });
        //dynamic
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.ACTION2);
                //since it's registered a local, use the LocalBroadcastManager.
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).sendBroadcast(i);
                //use this if registered as a global receiver.
                //getActivity().sendBroadcast(i);
                Log.v("MainActivity", "Should have sent the broadcast.");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(MyReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION2));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(MyReceiver != null)
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(MyReceiver);
        Log.v("MainActivity", "receiver should be unregistered");
    }

}
```

MyBroadcastReceiver:

```
 public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Received an intent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (intent.getAction().equals(MainActivity.ACTION1)) { //is it our action1?
            Toast.makeText(context, "We received an intent for Action1.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(MainActivity.ACTION2)) { //is it our action2?
            Toast.makeText(context, "We received an intent for Action2.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver  android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.test.add.mystaticevent"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Application 2:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private MyBroadcastReceiver MyReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        MyReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.test.add.mystaticevent");
        if(intentFilter != null)
        {
            registerReceiver(MyReceiver, intentFilter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(MyReceiver != null)
            unregisterReceiver(MyReceiver);
    }
```

MyBroadcastReceiver: (data is not receiving)

```
  public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("data"); //I am not receiving this data
        Toast.makeText(context,data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        Log.i("BROADCAST RECEIVING" ,"Data received:  " + data);
    }
}
```

Mainfest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver  android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.test.add.mystaticevent"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```